# Ensure that program crash on runtime error at proper place in C++/fortran

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, fortran

**In short:**

Is there some general and reliable way to ensure that program always crashes at place where some bad thing ( like writing to memory which does not belong to me ) happened ?

Eg. some `gcc flags` like `-Og -g -fbounds-check` ... ?

( resp. `g++` / `gfortran` )

---

**Longer explanation:**

Real example which I want to avoid:

Usually, when I meet an runtime error I write a bunch of numbered debug messages into the code like `printf("DEBUG %i \n", 15 );` to see where it exactly crashed (in Java it works well).

But recently I by mistake wrote outside allocated array by piece of code functionally similar to this:

```
int ny = 6;
int nz = 60;
zs = new double[ny];
for(int i=0; i<nz; i++){
    zs[i] = i/(double)nz;
}
```

however, instead of triggering segmentation fault immediately, this error manifested itself by `memory corruption` at completely unrelated place ( inside method of different object called 20 lines later, namely at mouse handling rutine `SDL_pollEvent()` ).

I totally could not understand how mouse handling can be connected with the part of code (initialization of that array) I was working on. So it took me very long time to find it.

I also tried to use `gdb`, debugger in `Code::Blocks` and even `Valgrind` to find the error ( even though I'm not very familiar with its usage ) ... but all of them indicated just that memory corruption happened in `SDL_pollEvent()`

Some time ago I had similar problem with fortran (not sure if `ifort` or `gfortran` )

Comment: Laudable goal, but unfortunately there are no solutions which work well with optimized productions builds. Any memory checking of such nature would impose performance hit, memory hit or both. For debug-level builds, gcc now has built-in ASan - you can look into it.

Comment: You think that is bad?   'Bad' is the issue cropping up in a different thread, performing completely unrelated work, and at varying lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fortran, at least use array bounds checking and pointer checking (`-fcheck=all`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html). It is not almighty, but can save you quite often. In particular, it is able to diagnose that kind of error you have in your example. It also can diagnose, when you are still within the right buffer, but you are off in one of the dimensions as in

```
   allocate(a(10,10))
   ...
   x = a(11,1)
```

C (dynamic) arrays usually cannot be checked so easily, as they are just an address. You can use sanitizations for both C and Fortran, but they are more expensive. It is enabled by `fsanitize=...`, see the compiler manual for all possibilities, there is no `=all` as in `-fcheck`.

Comment: thanks, [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) ( `-fsanitize=address` and `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` with `gcc` version > 4.8 ) is probably exactly what I'm searchning for. The slow down for debugging is not a problem. Just, from practical point, I didn't get yet how to use it with `Code::Blocks` especially when `.cdb` project is generated by `CMake`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't ensure that a program crash reliably and consistently. C++ doesn't require that the code check explicitly for actions that cause undefined behavior, so the results are totally unpredictable. When you cause memory corruption, it can be anywhere in the process's memory. Whether and when this results in a crash depends on what happens to be in the memory that you corrupted, and how it's used later in the program.

In C++, your best bet is to avoid using low-level, C-style arrays and pointers, and make use of high-level data structures like `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::shared_ptr`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. A C++ program can only crash if it invokes undefined behaviour, and that means anything can happen - including ignoring any diagnostics you might happen to have added.

(Sorry, can't help with Fortran.)